# SPOJ dynamic programming with BigInteger - SETNJA

Tags: c, dynamic, recursion

I was trying to solve the following spoj problem http://www.spoj.pl/problems/SETNJA/

I implemented it using recursion but the limit is quite high which will not fit in unsigned long long. On forums everyone is saying to implement it using Dynamic programming. Can anyone plz explain how to do it using DP. Here is my effort using recursion. Its correct but the answer will not fit in unsigned long long. Any hint will be appreciated

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long long ULLD;
ULLD ans=0ull;
char str[10001];
int length;
void recurse(int i, ULLD temp)
{
    if(str[i]=='\0')
    {
        ans=ans+temp;
        return;
    }
    if(str[i]=='L') recurse(i+1,2*temp);
    else if(str[i]=='R') recurse(i+1,2*temp+1);
    else if(str[i]=='P') recurse(i+1,temp);
    else if(str[i]=='*')
    {
        recurse(i+1, 2*temp);
        recurse(i+1 , 2*temp +1);
        recurse(i+1, temp);
    }
}

int main()
{   
    scanf("%s",str);
    length=strlen(str);

    recurse(0,1);

    printf("%llu",ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A walk of depth 10000 with no wildcards or pauses will have a value of 10000 binary digits.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Didn't get it :(

Comment: It's actually 100001 binary digits, my bad. Each L or R step amounts to appending 0 or 1 to the current node value, in binary. 10000 steps will append 10000 bits.

Comment: I can't understand why my recursion is wrong? And why should I use dynamic programming?